# Relative date in grouped filter does not show textfield for data

Tags: views, datetime

I have a problem with grouped filters. I want to specify a relative date but a textfield does not appear. My result was
[image]

I want to achieve something like this below.
[image]

Credits to the owner of the pic.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any JS errors?

Comment: I have checked the javascript console and the errors were
 'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead.
jquery.js:139 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem?